# Prevent context.consumer from re-rendering component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have created the following context provider. In sort it's a toast generator. It can have multiple toasts visible at the same time.

It all worked great and such until I realized that the `<Component/>` further down the tree that called the `const context = useContext(ToastContext)` aka the consumer of this context and the creator of the toast notifications, was also re-rendering when the **providerValue** was changing.

I tried to prevent that, changing the `useMemo` to a `useState` hook for the **providerValue**, which did stop my re-rendering problem , but now I could only have 1 toast active at a time (because toasts was never updated inside the add function).

Is there a way to have both my scenarios?

```
export const withToastProvider = (Component) => {
  const WithToastProvider = (props) => {
    const [toasts, setToasts] = useState([])
    const add = (toastSettings) => {
      const id = generateUEID()
      setToasts([...toasts, { id, toastSettings }])
    }
    const remove = (id) => setToasts(toasts.filter((t) => t.id !== id))
    // const [providerValue] = useState({ add, remove })
    const providerValue = React.useMemo(() => {
      return { add, remove }
    }, [toasts])

    const renderToasts = toasts.map((t, index) => (
      <ToastNote key={t.id} remove={() => remove(t.id)} {...t.toastSettings} />
    ))

    return (
      <ToastContext.Provider value={providerValue}>
        <Component {...props} />
        <ToastWrapper>{renderToasts}</ToastWrapper>
      </ToastContext.Provider>
    )
  }

  return WithToastProvider
}
```

Comment: `useContext` is meant to re-render the component when its value changes.Don't try to avoid that. You probably should re-structure your component tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @cbdeveloper, I figured it out.

The problem was not on my Context but on the caller. I needed to use a `useMemo()` there to have memoized the part of the component that didnt need to update.

Comment: Please may you provide context on your solution?
Having almost exactly this issue

Comment: const WithToastProvider = withToastProvider(React.memo(() => (children)))

and then I called <WithToastProvider /> inside my AppConsumer

Comment: Ah, thank you, I found a similar solution in which I wrapped the context's state modifiers in useCallback which resolved my issue.
I would imagine this achieves the same or similar result but differs in where the memoization occurs, perhaps use case dependent? (thanks again!)